# Error issuing part using Maximo integration framework MXINVISSUE

Tags: maximo

We are upgrading from Maximo 7.5 to 7.6.1. Our web service that uses MXINVISSUEInterface is throwing an exception when we try to issue a part that is marked as a spare part and the work order has an asset. The exception says "BMXAA4195 - A value is required for the Organization field on the SPAREOBJECT object."  The part is not in the SPAREPART table for the asset so it is trying to add it, but for some reason the ORGID is not populated from the MXINVISSUE_MATUSETRANSType object.

I re-generated the WSDL on the new server and rebuilt the solution, but after populate a new required field, I still get the same error.

Is there a system property that must be set.  It works in 7.5 writing the record to MATUSETRANS and SPAREPART.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug, so you might raise a Support Case with IBM about it. For a workaround until IBM releases a fix and you install said fix, consider the following options.

1. Can you set the Default Insert Site for the user using the web service?
2. Is it practical to put a Default Value on `SPAREPART.ORGID`?
3. Create an automation script called `SPAREPART.NEW` that will somehow figure out an `ORGID` to use. To "figure out", my first would be to check if `mbo` has an owner that has an `ORGID` and, assuming it does, use that.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. The property mxe.int.dfltuser was set to maxintadm which wasn't set up in the person table. It must the organization from there in SPAREPART. I changed it to the user the old version had and now it works.